# How to sort a list based on the first element with empty elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Your function returned the following :

`[[], [5 ], [4 ], [5 4 ]]`

The expected returned value :

`[[], [4 ], [4 5 ], [5 ]]`

So I did this to sort my list: `result.sort(key = lambda x : x[0])`

it gives me an error since [] has not index 0

I also tried `result.sort(key = lambda x : x[0] if x != [])`

but it says invalid syntax. How to do this ?

I am trying to print all the combinations for a given list:

```
def subsetsWithDup(self, A):
        size = len(A)
        power = pow(2, size)
        result = []
        temp = []
        for i in range(power):
            for j in range(size):
                if (i & (1 << j)) > 0:
                    temp.append(A[j])
            result.append(temp)
            temp = []
        return result
```

Function call:

```
subsetsWithDup([5,4])
```

Comment: You can use a conditional expression. But why not just define a function?

Comment: What does `result` look like?

Comment: I thought it is possible using `sort()` and `lambda()`

Comment: @Austin result is the returned list: `[[], [5], [4], [5,4]]`

Comment: What is generating "result"? This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: result.sort() will do

Comment: @Austin I added it all

Comment: Inside your function, do `result.append(sorted(temp))`, and then sort the result as `sorted(result, key=lambda x: bool(x) and x[0])`

Comment: Your example shows the sub lists changing order as well. You show `[[], [5 ], [4 ], [5 4 ]]` but then `[[], [4 ], [4 5 ], [5 ]]` so the `5,4` is being sorted to `4,5`. That is a different problem than you are stating.

Comment: @coldspeed Thank you so much. It worked but returned another error when the returned was `[[3,6], [3,3]]` where the expected is `[[3,3], [3,6]]`

Comment: Have subsetsWithDup work with a local copy of sorted(A), because sorting the input first will be much faster than sorting all combinations of the input. I'm just guessing without proof that your combinations will be ordered as a result of pre-sorting. (Why not use itertools.combinations instead?)

Comment: For you *stated* problem (sort with a lambda with empty sub lists) you can do `sorted(your_list, key=lambda sl: sl[0] if sl else some_value_lower_than_any_list_entry)`

Comment: Try instead `sorted(result, key=lambda x: (bool(x), tuple(x)))`

Comment: @coldspeed Thank you soooo much it worked!!

Comment: @coldspeed: How is that different from just `sorted(your_list)`?  Empty (sub)lists already sort first.

Comment: What would `x[0] if x!=[]` **mean** if (it were valid and) `x` were empty?